# How to put my name, current date and paper title in the header of every page?

Tags: header-footer, lyx

I just started using Lyx and I'm very confused. It doesn't allow me to show the LaTeX code so that I cannot edit LaTeX directly. But it also has no apparent options to set certain things.

What I need is this:

[image: the tex]

Comment: This depends on the packages and the documentclass, but I would try either `fancyhdr` package or the KOMA classes for this

Comment: I should've pointed out I'm a beginner with LaTeX. Therefore I have frankly no idea what are you talking about. I tried putting some `fancyhdr` commands in LaTeX preambule, but where to put the desired information I have no idea. I found these codes here, on tex.SE - so yes, I have been searching a lot before posting.

Comment: You might wanna tell us a bit more about what kind  of document you are working on. You can also read [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) to make a decision on your own.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's possible to enter `LateX` code directly into LyX editor.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, but it doesn't render then. It remains in a red block and only renders when you compile to PDF. Also can you explain your edit on my question? LyX or LaTeX are not code, they are platform names. I don't put `Christian` in code block, or should I?

Comment: @TomášZato: Reverted the edit ;-)

Comment: Why don't you use an editor which *does* let you see the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various possibilities, this just uses the `scrbook` class and the `scrlayer-scrpage` package, setting the headers for left-header-odd-page (`\lohead`), left-header-even-page (`\lehead`) and their corresponding commands for the right headers, as well as the centred head command `\chead`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % Koma book class
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand{\MyName}{Tom\'a\v{s} Zato}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\clearscrheadfoot%
\rohead{\MyName}
\lehead{\today}

\chead{Project}
\lohead{\today}
\rehead{\MyName}    
\cefoot{\thepage}  % Page number in centred footer

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\blindtext[5]  % Filling the document
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version for an `oneside` book - document

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand{\MyName}{Tom\'a\v{s} Zato}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\clearscrheadfoot%
\ohead{\MyName}
\ihead{\today}
\chead{Project}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\blindtext[6]


\end{document}
```

Comment: By the OPs input, i would guess this is a `oneside` document. Having the project name in the header also clues for oneside. Even if it would be twoside, having the name always on the right is messy. Decide for inner/center/outside. Makes less code as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I took my inspirations from the images ;-)

Comment: The images clearly show an article-kind-of-document. :-p

Comment: @Johannes_B: Clearly? A sketch by hand identifies as `article-like`? (i.e. with equal margins)

Comment: Never said `article`, but article-kind-of-document.

Answer (score 3):

In the settings dialog click on the Modules option.

Select "Custom Header/Footerlines" from the "Available" list and then click on the "Add" button to make it active. Note the advice in the description pane that you must set the Page Layout to "fancy". (Click on the "Page Layout" option and select "fancy" from the "Page style" drop down. Click on "OK" to close the settings dialog.

This will then give you a series of environments in your environment list which you can insert into your LyX document which you can use to set headers and footers using LyX commands. For example, if you select "Left Header" from the list with your cursor in a new paragraph you will see the text "Left Header:" appear in your document. Just type the content of the header in this environment.

Personally, I set these up at the start of the document so they are easy to find.

No LaTeX or preamble changes necessary.